# How to set different root folder access for different roles in elFinder

Tags: 7, files

I'm using drupal 7.69 and elFinder 2.1.46.
A private page is showing elFinder browsing window with 2 root folders

```
root1
   |-dir1
   |-dir2
root2
   |-dir3
   |-dir4
```

I am trying to setup 2 roles:

- role 1 has **r/w** access to root1 and **r/o** access to root2
- role 2 has **r/o** access to root1 and **r/w** access to root2

I've gone through the Drupal permissions, but they apply to all folders and files served by elFinder.
I've looked at profiles in Configuration > Media > elFinder, but it does not seem like there is anything about level of access in there.
I have read through https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Simple-file-permissions-control which advises to set the access rights in connector.php, but the Drupal module version also advises to delete connector.php after install for security purposes.
Finally, older messages on gitlab seem to imply that there is no refined file-level permission control options in the Drupal module yet.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to set different access rights on folders (root folders at least) for different roles?
2. If so, how is it done?

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a support request to a third-party dependency hosted on drupal.org or elsewhere. It must be reported in the corresponding issue queue over there to track changes at a single place to help fix their documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, and please excuse my misguided posting if I did not come to the right place. I will also post my question at https://gitlab.com/667bdrm/elfinder/issues

Comment: Oh, interesting, that drupal elfinder module is BSD-3 licensed, when it <a href="https://www.drupal.org/about/licensing#project-licensing">shouldn't be</a>.